# Laravel роутинг не работает

Tags: php, apache, laravel

Не работает роутинг в Laravel. Например у меня домен http://crm.loc но роуты типа http://crm.loc/login не работают, но работает http://crm.loc/index.php/login 
файл .htaccess стандартный лежит в папке public

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>






Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName crm.loc
    ServerAlias www.crm.loc
    ServerAdmin troopermanowar@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/crm/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/crm/public">
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>




  Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
```

Comment: Так покажите его, и проверьте что mod_rewrite включен.

Comment: Конфиг виртуал хоста покажите, может в нём дело.

Comment: И на всякий случай, покажите как вы пробросили роут

Comment: DirectoryIndex index.php ... прописан?

Comment: Это в конфиге хоста надо писать или в глобальном конфиге апача? В конфиг хоста добавил - не помогло.

Comment: если запустить php artisan serve работает?

Comment: если запустить php artisan serve работает

Comment: <Directory "/var/www/crm">
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory> вот так попробуйте

Answer (score 1):

Должно выполняться несколько условий:

- включен модуль rewrite у apache
- правильно настроеный виртуальный хост
- правильный .htaccess

Модуль у апача включается на разных системах по разному. В linux это будет примерно так:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Пример конфига для apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName site.local
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/site/public
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/site/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Ну, а .htaccess можно использовать "родной" от laravel.

Answer (score -1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```